# Upload com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho seguinte **código**:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   
 $("form").on("submit", function() {

   $.post ("upload.php", {
    
    fotos : $("input[type=file]")
    
   }, function(retorno){
           
    alert(retorno)  
     }
    );

    return false;
  
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<form 
  method="post" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" id="imagens" name="imagens[]" multiple /> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

upload.php

```
<?php

  print_r($_FILES);

?>
```

Esse **código** tem 2 problemas:

A) *Trava*, *solta* e depois faz **reload** e não para no `return false`

B) Como fazer para enviar o campo file até o **jQuery** mas com todas as imagens selecionadas? Obs.: da forma que está apenas chegam as informações da primeira imagem selecionada no array **jQuery**.

Answer (score 1):

Solução:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
  
   $("form").on("submit", function() {

  var formData = new FormData(this); 
  
  $.ajax({
   url: "upload.php",
   type: 'POST',
   data: formData,
   beforeSend: function() {      
   },
   success: function (data) {
   },
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false
  });
  
  return false;
    
   });
   
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<form 
  method="post"
  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" id="imagens" name="imagens[]" multiple /> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

upload.php

```
  print "<pre>";
  print_r($_FILES);
  print "</pre>";
```

Comment: Eu já ia responder que o $.post serve para ler e não para enviar :D

Comment: Vdd. Era o meu erro. Mas fica ai a orientação para alguém!